# can't get my ionic application correctly in genymotion emulator

Tags: android, ionic-framework

I'am working on a projet with ionic framework,I work with netbeans,Ripple chrome extension,every thing works right,any change I do it considering the Ripple extension,but when I try to test the application in the genymotion emulator,I get the application but with missing parts.I don't know why :/

NB:I use genymotion emulator with samsung galaxy S4 API 17 and
this is my AndroidManifest.xml in the projet (platform android)

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<manifest android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:versionCode="10000" android:versionName="1.0.0" package="com.coolappz.ProjetMobile1" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <supports-screens android:anyDensity="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:resizeable="true" android:smallScreens="true" android:xlargeScreens="true" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <application android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name" android:supportsRtl="true">
        <activity android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale" android:label="@string/activity_name" android:launchMode="singleTop" android:name="MainActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <intent-filter android:label="@string/launcher_name">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="17" android:targetSdkVersion="21" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_VIDEO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
</manifest>
```

thanks for help

Update:
I use the cmd console 'ionic run android' to run the project on the genymotion emulator,this is the output:

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\testprjmobile\ProjetMobile1>ionic run android
running cordova run android
Running command: C:\xampp\htdocs\testprjmobile\ProjetMobile1\platforms\android\c
ordova\run.bat
WARNING : No target specified, deploying to device '192.168.56.101:5555'.
Buildfile: C:\xampp\htdocs\testprjmobile\ProjetMobile1\platforms\android\build.x
ml

-set-mode-check:

-set-debug-files:

-check-env:
 [checkenv] Android SDK Tools Revision 24.1.2
 [checkenv] Installed at D:\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20140702\sdk

-setup:
     [echo] Project Name: MainActivity
  [gettype] Project Type: Application

-set-debug-mode:

-debug-obfuscation-check:

-pre-build:

-build-setup:
[getbuildtools] Using latest Build Tools: 22.0.1
     [echo] Resolving Build Target for MainActivity...
[gettarget] Project Target:   Android 5.0.1
[gettarget] API level:        21
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Creating output directories if needed...
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Resolving Dependencies for MainActivity...
[dependency] Library dependencies:
[dependency]
[dependency] ------------------
[dependency] Ordered libraries:
[dependency]
[dependency] ------------------
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Building Libraries with 'debug'...

nodeps:

-set-mode-check:

-set-debug-files:

-check-env:
 [checkenv] Android SDK Tools Revision 24.1.2
 [checkenv] Installed at D:\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20140702\sdk

-setup:
     [echo] Project Name: MainActivity
  [gettype] Project Type: Android Library

-set-debug-mode:

-debug-obfuscation-check:

-pre-build:

-build-setup:
[getbuildtools] Using latest Build Tools: 22.0.1
     [echo] Resolving Build Target for MainActivity...
[gettarget] Project Target:   Android 5.0.1
[gettarget] API level:        21
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Creating output directories if needed...
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Resolving Dependencies for MainActivity...
[dependency] Library dependencies:
[dependency] No Libraries
[dependency]
[dependency] ------------------

-code-gen:
[mergemanifest] Found Deleted Target File
[mergemanifest] Merging AndroidManifest files into one.
[mergemanifest] Manifest merger disabled. Using project manifest only.
     [echo] Handling aidl files...
     [aidl] No AIDL files to compile.
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Handling RenderScript files...
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Handling Resources...
     [aapt] Found new input file
     [aapt] Generating resource IDs...
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Handling BuildConfig class...
[buildconfig] No need to generate new BuildConfig.

-pre-compile:

-compile:
     [echo] Creating library output jar file...

-post-compile:

-obfuscate:

-dex:
     [echo] Library project: do not convert bytecode...

-crunch:
   [crunch] Crunching PNG Files in source dir: C:\xampp\htdocs\testprjmobile\Pro
jetMobile1\platforms\android\CordovaLib\res
   [crunch] To destination dir: C:\xampp\htdocs\testprjmobile\ProjetMobile1\plat
forms\android\CordovaLib\ant-build\res
   [crunch] Crunched 0 PNG files to update cache

-package-resources:
     [echo] Library project: do not package resources...

-package:
     [echo] Library project: do not package apk...

-post-package:

-do-debug:
     [echo] Library project: do not create apk...
[propertyfile] Updating property file: C:\xampp\htdocs\testprjmobile\ProjetMobil
e1\platforms\android\CordovaLib\ant-build\build.prop
[propertyfile] Updating property file: C:\xampp\htdocs\testprjmobile\ProjetMobil
e1\platforms\android\CordovaLib\ant-build\build.prop
[propertyfile] Updating property file: C:\xampp\htdocs\testprjmobile\ProjetMobil
e1\platforms\android\CordovaLib\ant-build\build.prop
[propertyfile] Updating property file: C:\xampp\htdocs\testprjmobile\ProjetMobil
e1\platforms\android\CordovaLib\ant-build\build.prop

-post-build:

debug:

-code-gen:
[mergemanifest] Found Deleted Target File
[mergemanifest] Merging AndroidManifest files into one.
[mergemanifest] Manifest merger disabled. Using project manifest only.
     [echo] Handling aidl files...
     [aidl] No AIDL files to compile.
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Handling RenderScript files...
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Handling Resources...
     [aapt] Found Deleted Target File
     [aapt] Generating resource IDs...
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Handling BuildConfig class...
[buildconfig] No need to generate new BuildConfig.

-pre-compile:
     [echo] Set jars path to: C:\xampp\htdocs\testprjmobile\ProjetMobile1\platfo
rms\android\CordovaLib\ant-build\classes.jar

-compile:
    [javac] Compiling 2 source files to C:\xampp\htdocs\testprjmobile\ProjetMobi
le1\platforms\android\ant-build\classes
    [javac] warning: [options] source value 1.5 is obsolete and will be removed
in a future release
    [javac] warning: [options] target value 1.5 is obsolete and will be removed
in a future release
    [javac] warning: [options] To suppress warnings about obsolete options, use
-Xlint:-options.
    [javac] 3 warnings

-post-compile:

-obfuscate:

-dex:
      [dex] input: C:\xampp\htdocs\testprjmobile\ProjetMobile1\platforms\android
\ant-build\classes
      [dex] input: C:\xampp\htdocs\testprjmobile\ProjetMobile1\platforms\android
\CordovaLib\ant-build\classes.jar
      [dex] Using Pre-Dexed classes-c1d186ba21e27901b5f43be3d7b999ff.jar <- C:\x
ampp\htdocs\testprjmobile\ProjetMobile1\platforms\android\CordovaLib\ant-build\c
lasses.jar
      [dex] Found Deleted Target File
      [dex] Converting compiled files and external libraries into C:\xampp\htdoc
s\testprjmobile\ProjetMobile1\platforms\android\ant-build\classes.dex...
       [dx] Merged dex A (126 defs/205.1KiB) with dex B (223 defs/325.7KiB). Res
ult is 349 defs/648.7KiB. Took 0.3s

-crunch:
   [crunch] Crunching PNG Files in source dir: C:\xampp\htdocs\testprjmobile\Pro
jetMobile1\platforms\android\res
   [crunch] To destination dir: C:\xampp\htdocs\testprjmobile\ProjetMobile1\plat
forms\android\ant-build\res
   [crunch] Crunched 0 PNG files to update cache

-package-resources:
     [aapt] Found Deleted Target File
     [aapt] Creating full resource package...
     [aapt]     (skipping file '.editorconfig' due to ANDROID_AAPT_IGNORE patter
n '.*')
     [aapt]     (skipping file '.gitignore' due to ANDROID_AAPT_IGNORE pattern '
.*')
     [aapt]     (skipping file '.jshintrc' due to ANDROID_AAPT_IGNORE pattern '.
*')
     [aapt]     (skipping file '.npmignore' due to ANDROID_AAPT_IGNORE pattern '
.*')
     [aapt]     (skipping file '.travis.yml' due to ANDROID_AAPT_IGNORE pattern
'.*')
     [aapt]     (skipping file '.jshintrc' due to ANDROID_AAPT_IGNORE pattern '.
*')

-package:
[apkbuilder] Found Deleted Target File
[apkbuilder] Creating MainActivity-debug-unaligned.apk and signing it with a deb
ug key...

-post-package:

-do-debug:
 [zipalign] Running zip align on final apk...
     [echo] Debug Package: C:\xampp\htdocs\testprjmobile\ProjetMobile1\platforms
\android\ant-build\MainActivity-debug.apk
[propertyfile] Updating property file: C:\xampp\htdocs\testprjmobile\ProjetMobil
e1\platforms\android\ant-build\build.prop
[propertyfile] Updating property file: C:\xampp\htdocs\testprjmobile\ProjetMobil
e1\platforms\android\ant-build\build.prop
[propertyfile] Updating property file: C:\xampp\htdocs\testprjmobile\ProjetMobil
e1\platforms\android\ant-build\build.prop
[propertyfile] Updating property file: C:\xampp\htdocs\testprjmobile\ProjetMobil
e1\platforms\android\ant-build\build.prop

-post-build:
     [move] Moving 1 file to C:\xampp\htdocs\testprjmobile\ProjetMobile1\platfor
ms\android\ant-build
     [move] Moving 1 file to C:\xampp\htdocs\testprjmobile\ProjetMobile1\platfor
ms\android\CordovaLib\ant-build

debug:

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 52 seconds
Built the following apk(s):
    C:\xampp\htdocs\testprjmobile\ProjetMobile1\platforms\android\ant-build\Main
Activity-debug.apk
Using apk: C:\xampp\htdocs\testprjmobile\ProjetMobile1\platforms\android\ant-bui
ld\MainActivity-debug.apk
Installing app on device...
Launching application...
LAUNCH SUCCESS
```

the same problem with my samsung galaxy S4 smartphone,I get a large web views

Comment: are you recieving any errors? if so, can you add them to your question?

Comment: Hi  Bradley Wilson no there's not any error,I use the cmd to run the application on the genymotion emulator, :(

Comment: If I try to send the application to the phonegap build,then download it from my phone?is it a good solution

Comment: great initiative, phonegap is a solid framework for encorporating browser compatibility issues. But i'm unsure on the emulation process. I'll have a look around for you and see if there is anything saying otherwise.

Comment: Hmm you seem to using the correct command to run and the correct api to build and i can't see any obvious faults with your manifest file. i'll think on it, don't make any drastic changes as of yet

Comment: thanks Mr.Bradley Wilson:)